# Apps from the Apple App Store won't install on a macOS Mac mini EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-ec2

I am running a macOS Mac mini EC2 instance. I have an apple ID and went to the app store and tried to download a free app but it does not actually install. It just shows it loading forever without opening.

Any clue as to what this is? Is there some problem with the settings to prevent apps from installing?

Comment: What macOS? I've noticed it won't load in a Parallels VM either, but all my VMs are 'old' OSes which struggle a bit anyway these days, El Capitan is the newest. [El Cap running regularly on hardware does not have the same issue, though.]

Comment: M1 or Intel? AWS's docs for Mac minis in EC2 say in-place software updates aren't supported on M1, and have to be handled carefully on Intel. It's unclear from the docs if that just applies to OS updates or other software (apps) as well.

Answer (score 1):

This issue only happens to me on mac1.metal (x86 / intel) running Ventura. It worked previously on mac1.metal running macOS Monterey. I am able to install applications from app store using mac2.metal (ARM / M1) running Ventura.

I opened a ticket with AWS and they provided the following workaround:

1. Create necessary directory in terminal by running: sudo install -d -o _biome -g _biome -m 0700 /private/var/db/biome
2. Logging out & logging back into graphical session

This fixed the issue for me.

AWS expects to release a fix in the new AWS-vended macOS 13.4 AMI which will come shortly after Apple releases the production version of macOS 13.4.