# AWS EC2 mac1 instance cannot connect to iCloud or App Store

Tags: macos, mac, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ios

My team is looking into utilizing MacOS EC2 build agents for our iOS builds. I set up the instance as described in [the AWS documentation](https://catalog.us-east-1.prod.workshops.aws/workshops/5ced3c00-8e8a-4c4d-82fa-ca1b7804ea4d/en-US/instance-setup/dedicated-host). The x86 instance (mac1) doesn't seem to be able to install anything on the App Store (Xcode, Transporter, etc.) or access iCloud (the same behaviour as [this thread](https://superuser.com/questions/1753717/apps-from-the-apple-app-store-wont-install-on-a-macos-mac-mini-ec2-instance), but I narrowed down the problem to `mac1` instance as this doesn't seem to be a problem on the `mac2` (Apple Silicon) family instance). Can anyone shed some light on why this is the case? Is this a bug on their end or is there a configuration step that I missed?